# Blank White Terminal in Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Tags: command-line, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I added and installed these two repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

In a stupid attempt to update to the most recent drivers my terminal / dropdown menus in MATE Tweak are now showing up as blank white:

[image: Screenshot]

I have since purged the repositories, but nothing has worked...

I have an Intel HD4000 integrated graphics card. Any ideas?